# Simple Program Being Paused Somewhere in ntdll

Tags: ollydbg, c

The following is a simple program I wrote to be debugged in OllyDbg:

```
main(){
    exit(0);
}
```

I compiled the program and opened it in OllyDbg. The program pauses at some weird location in ntdll. I went into options and set a breakpoint at the entry. The program still paused at the same location in ntdll. I then set a breakpoint at main. And it still pauses at some location in ntdll.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of OllyDbg are you using?

Answer (score 2):

The first break is always the system breakpoint.

If you do not want Ollydbg to stop at system breakpoint goto options.

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> -> events and change the make first pause at to EntryPoint Of Main module

When, a parent process creates a child with `DEBUG_XXXX` flags it should know when the process initialisation has been finished so a notification called `ProcessCreate DebugEvent` is raised `DbgBreakPoint` in `ntdll.dll` is a part of that `DebugEvent Notification` usually termed as `SystemBreakPoint`.

Which version of Ollydbg are you using 1.10 or 2.01, do you have plugins loaded ? 
A simple executable with just an exit should either stop on `System BreakPoint` or `WinMainCrtStartup` or at `main()` only not anywhere else.

Comment: I did that though, that's the thing. It stills breaks at the system break point. Can I ask what's so special about the "system breakpoint." Is it unique? Why choose it?